# Getting unique data gives User memory limit exceeded using Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I want to get the unique data in GEE, but I get:

> User memory limit exceeded.

There are 3000 points in FeatureCollection.

Should I reduce the count of points?

```
var relu5 = function(fc){
  var test_Data = ee.FeatureCollection(fc)

  var label_count = test_Data.aggregate_array("label").distinct()
  
  return label_count
}
var list_point = relu4_relues.toList(relu4_relues.size())
var label_sum = list_point.map(relu5)
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't provided complete code, so I don't know what all of the involved types are, but in general, avoid doing this whenever possible:

```js
var list_point = relu4_relues.toList(relu4_relues.size())
```

Using `FeatureCollection.toList()` with the full size always brings the *entire* feature collection into memory at once — including any properties and geometry you aren't using. Thus using it in this way is a common cause of hitting the memory limit.

Instead, map over the FeatureCollection itself. In order to do this you'll need to return results as features instead of other value types, but you can then use `reduceColumns` to extract the data from the collection.

```js
var relu5 = function(fc){
  var test_Data = ee.FeatureCollection(fc);

  var label_count = test_Data.aggregate_array("label").distinct();
  
  return ee.Feature(null, {'label_count': label_count});
}

var label_sum = relu4_relues
  .map(relu5)
  .reduceColumns(ee.Reducer.toList(), ['label_count'])
  .get('list');  // toList's output is named 'list'
```

`reduceColumns` with `Reducer.toList` is a better tool here than `FeatureCollection.toList`, because the *only* thing it collects into an in-memory list is the property (column) you asked for, not any of the other data.